# play tones from list in psychopy3

Tags: python, audio, psychopy

If I have a list of stimulus names for tones, either written in code or pulled up from an excel file using xlrd, how do I play them using code in psychopy?

```
# For example, if my tones are
lo = sound.backend_sounddevice.SoundDeviceSound(value='A', 
           secs=0.05, octave=4, stereo=-1, volume=1.0, 
           loops=0, sampleRate=44100, blockSize=128, 
           preBuffer=- 1, hamming=True, startTime=0, 
           stopTime=- 1, name='', autoLog=True) 
       
hi = sound.backend_sounddevice.SoundDeviceSound(value='B', 
           secs=0.05, octave=4, stereo=-1, volume=1.0, 
           loops=0, sampleRate=44100, blockSize=128, 
           preBuffer=- 1, hamming=True, startTime=0, 
           stopTime=- 1, name='', autoLog=True) 

# and the stimulus list is
tone_stimuli = ['hi', 'hi', 'lo', 'hi', 'lo']

# and I want to play them in order with a command like
hi.play() # which plays the high tone
```

What is the code I need in order for this to play the high tone, high tone, low tone, high tone, low tone, in sequence, as in the tone_stimuli list?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
current_tone = str(tone_stimuli[0])
current_tone.play()
```

(At the end of the day I need to make an audio-visual experiment where tones play in the background of the visual task, and independently of the visual trials. To do so, the tones need to be played using code, and need to pre-exist in a list, so workarounds where the tones are called in Builder unfortunately won't work in this case.)

Comment: Can you play a single tone not in a list?

Comment: Good question @fdcpp. Yes, a tone plays with hi.play()

Comment: Wonderful, next step would be, can you play two tones in succession, again not in a list?

Comment: Yes indeed, I can do that @fdcpp. I have put them in a loop and set the clock timer so that a tone is played every second, for example. I can also use a loop and do if current_tone[i] == 'hi': hi.play(). That works nicely. It's just that in my auditory experiment timing is crucial, and it takes some precious milliseconds to run a for loop, so I am hoping to fix that by reading the tones off a pre-made list.

Comment: Can you also share that script with playing tones via a for loop?